# Activate CAB menu when OnClickEvent happens in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-gridview, android-menu, contextual-action-bar

Trying to activate CAB menu when clicking on MenuItem from ActionBar. Here is how I set the GridView for listening to Multi Choice. The multiModeChoiceListener is working fine when I long press on Any item in the GridView. It is working fine. Now I have a requirement to activate the CAB menu when do press on a menu item in Action Bar. Once it is pressed, the CAB menu should read that 0 items are selected. After that it should allow me to select items from GridView on single clicks. How can I achieve this feature?

GridView set listener:

```
gv.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL); 
gv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());
```

MultiChoiceModeListener.java

```
public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements
    GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {  

public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.featured_multiselect, menu);
    MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.close);
    mi.setIcon(R.drawable.cancel);
    mode.setTitle("Select Items");
    return true;
}

public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {    
    return true;
}

public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Close")) {
        mode.finish();
    }
    return true;
}

public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    new ChangeNotifier().changeOnFavoriteStore = true;
    new AddFavorites().execute("add", device_id, dataArray);
    if (notify == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Selected items are added to Favorites",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        notify = false;
    }
}

public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
        long id, boolean checked) {
    int selectCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
    if (selectCount > 0) {
        notify = true;              
        dataArray.add(position);
        switch (selectCount) {
        case 1:
            mode.setSubtitle("One item added to favorites");
            break;
        default:
            mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount
                    + " items added to favorites");
            break;
        }
    } 

   }
```

OnMenuItemClick method:

```
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    final MenuItem editItem = menu.findItem(R.id.editit);

    editItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            //the CAB menu should be activated here. So that it reads that 0 items are selected in ActionBar

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I understand that you're trying to start the `GridView` associated CAB from clicking one of the menu items. I don't know if you can do this(but I may be mistaken) as the `MultiChoiceModeListener` expects an item to be checked to start. Depending on your layout and the overall appearance of the `GridView`, I think you could have a dummy item(as an extra item in the adapter) at the end of the `GridView`(with no content showing) and use `setItemChecked(dummyItemPosition, true)` to start the `GridView` CAB. Of course you'll need to have additional logic to take care of that extra item in your `MultiChoiceModeListener`:

```
 public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
        long id, boolean checked) {
    if (position == theDummyPosition)
         return; // so we start the CAB but there aren't any items checked
    }
    int selectCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
    if (selectCount > 0) {
        notify = true;              
        dataArray.add(position);
        // if you select another item you'll have two selected items(because of the dummy item) so you need to take care of it 
        switch (selectCount) {
        case 1:
            mode.setSubtitle("One item added to favorites");
            break;
        default:
            mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount
                    + " items added to favorites");
            break;
        }
    } 

   }
```

The solution above is a hack, most likely it would be much easier to lose the `MultiChoiceModeListener` and simply start an `ActionMode` that you can manipulate for both situations.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and let you know.