# How can i start the action mode of a MultiChoiceModeListener from a ListView

Tags: android, listview, contextual-action-bar

I've implemented a contextual action bar(CAB) with multiple selection in a listview. (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598553/940637).

Now i would to implement a editbutton, which needs to trigger the CAB to be shown. Is there anyway how this can be done?

I've tried startActionMode (but than i need to implement a separate callback), which i don't like.

Comment: Do you want to do something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128558/activate-cab-menu-when-onclickevent-happens-in-android ?

Comment: ye indeed.. It looks like the easiest way to do this, is by is by hacking a dummy item in the listview..

Comment: If I were in your place I would go with using a simple `ActionMode`(even for the `ListView`) instead of the `MultiChoiceModeListener` that should be much easier to manipulate than an dummy view.

Comment: ye ok, i think your right.

Comment: OK thnx, i got it working with my own ActionMode. Afterall it wasnt that hard:P

Comment: @Luizje it's helpful to the SO community if you post your solution as an answer.