# GridView delete multiple items like iphone apps uninstallation View

Tags: android, iphone, gridview, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` in which I am showing list of books. I have tried by creating custom layout and putting cancel button onlongclick listener of a view. But i am not able to apply a shaking animation to the items. Can anyone guide me how can i apply an animation to the items and make it similarly like iphone?

Now **I want to provide feature to delete the Multiple items from the `GridView`** like the `View` which shows as below:

[image]

I did lots of research for this ,but failed to get such kind of view in Android.

Can any one guide me for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14128558/115145

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a custom gridview for that. Place a button (x) on top of the grid item and set its visibility to invisible.. onLongPress of the *grid item*, make that button *visible*.. onclick of the button, delete that grid item by getting its id.

Hope I have given you a direction.

Comment: I have did that but i also to give an animation like shaking like iPhone.

Comment: you should update the question then. I gave the answer according to the question.